# Chart.js version 2.5 tooltip align items horizontally

Tags: javascript, chart.js, tooltip

I am working on chart.js version 2.5

Currently values are displaying vertical, i want to display horizontally.

Some of the advance charts has 20 values.

Please check the below attached image.

**Intended results:**

- White or Caucasian and Black or African american in one row
- Asian other and Asian Japanese in another row

[image]

```
        tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        bodyFontSize: 14,
        titleFontSize: 14,
        xPadding: 20,
        yPadding: 20,
        multiKeyBackground: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                var prefix = data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label;
                return prefix + " : " + tooltipItems.yLabel;
            },
            title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                var value = tooltipItems[0].xLabel;
                return xAxisLabel + " : " + value;
            }
        }
    },
```

I tried to implement custom tooltip. as mentioned in https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks but not successful.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

After below answer by @Francisco Soares

**i am facing 1 issue**

- Tooltip is not removed when cursor moved.

Attached screenshot

[image]

**Update** 
Finally chart is working fine, one issue left offset. its going outside the chart.

Comment: Hi glad to see this is working, can you please share more information about the problem since I can't replicate it, or show the code that you have already implemented, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue 1 - Table content align center

The alignment can be changed with the following css:

```
#tooltip td {
  text-align: left;
}
```

### Issue 2 - Tooltip not being removed when cursor moved

I can't replicate this issue, since the function only uses one `div` with the id `tooltip` this shouldn't append.

The close I can get to this problem is if you have a different `id` in that case `chart.js` will create a new tooltip every time its attempts to render one. Here is an example:

[image]

So make sure the id is the same, and let me know this is the problem.

### Issue 3 - Tooltip position at end of canvas

Well another problem is at the end of the canvas the tooltip will warp to fit the chart, my proposal will be creating a offset so the tooltip will stay away from the borders:

Example 1 - Tooltip float to the other side of canvas

```
  var offset = tooltip.width + 20;
  if (this._chart.width / 2 < tooltip.caretX) {
    offset *= -1;
  }

  // Hidden Code
  tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + offset + 'px';
```

Example 2 - Tooltip limited to canvas size

```
  var offset = tooltip.caretX + 20;
  if (offset < tooltip.width)
    offset = tooltip.width;
  else if (tooltip.caretX > this._chart.width - tooltip.width)
    offset = this._chart.width - tooltip.width;

  // Hidden Code
  tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + offset + 'px';
```

See the working example.

### Solving the original problem

Using one of the samples, [this one](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/custom-line.html), is possible to change the function that adds the values to the tooltip `table` so in each odd/even value it creates a `tr`.

### A working example

```js
var customTooltips = function(tooltip) {
  // Tooltip Element
  var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('tooltip');

  if (!tooltipEl) {
    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
    tooltipEl.id = 'tooltip';
    tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
    this._chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
  }

  // Hide if no tooltip
  if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }

  // Set caret Position
  tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
  if (tooltip.yAlign) {
    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltip.yAlign);
  } else {
    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
  }

  function getBody(bodyItem) {
    return bodyItem.lines;
  }

  // Set Text
  if (tooltip.body) {
    var titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
    var bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(getBody);

    var innerHtml = '<thead>';

    titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
      innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
    });
    innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

    bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
      var colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];
      var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
      style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
      style += '; border-width: 2px';
      var span = '<span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="' + style + '"></span>';
      var innerContent = '<td>' + span + body + '</td>';
      // Every even/odd create a new tr
      if (i % 2 == 0)
        innerHtml += '<tr>' + innerContent;
      else
        innerHtml += innerContent + '</tr>';
    });
    // If is a odd number of itens close the last open tr
    if (bodyLines.count % 2 == 1)
      innerHtml += '</tr></tbody>';
    else
      innerHtml += '</tbody>';

    var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
  }

  var positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
  var positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;
  
  var offset = tooltip.caretX + 20;
  if (offset < tooltip.width)
    offset = tooltip.width;
  else if (tooltip.caretX > this._chart.width - tooltip.width)
    offset = this._chart.width - tooltip.width;
  
  // Display, position, and set styles for font
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
  tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + offset + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._bodyFontFamily;
  tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.bodyFontSize + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._bodyFontStyle;
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
};

var myChart = new Chart($('#myChart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 4'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dats asd asda 1',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)'
    }, {
      label: 'D 2',
      data: [13, 17, 4, 6],
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2)'
    }, {
      label: 'D 3',
      data: [14, 19, 3, 9],
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)'
    }, {
      label: 'Data 4',
      data: [15, 20, 2, 8],
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          suggestedMax: 50,
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
      custom: customTooltips
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 4px;
}

#tooltip td {
  text-align: left;
}

.chartjs-tooltip-key {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have updated my issues, in my question in the top please check.

Comment: I really dont know, why tooltips are not removed, when moving to another point. checking on that. i will update you by tomorrow.

Comment: Updated screenshot, please check. i am glad, we are very near to closing this issue.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa two questions, first please see my answer again and tell me if the solution for the issue doesn't work, if so, there is more than one chart in the page?

Comment: Now tooltip is working fine, one issue, last one i believe. Tooltip is becoming narrow width whenever i move cursor to the edge. let me know if you can fix this.?

Comment: another one issue is, i need to refresh the chart, each time to view the tooltip

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa I have updated my answer, see the working example if you have trouble understanding, to the fact that is needed to refresh the page to see the tooltip, please see the browser console and let me know if there is any output.

Comment: Hi Francisco, everything working now. i have just merged your code with <https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips>, only thing left, is left offset issue, described in question. if you can fix it that will be great, otherwise i will award you bounty tomorrow

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa Check the topic **Issue 3** and **Example** of my answer, I added a new spinet of code that limits the tooltip to the canvas size, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Final Function would be (Hope, someone it will **help in future**).

```
function buildChartOptions(xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel, pointStyle, position) {

    var options = {
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false,
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
            multiKeyBackground: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            bodyFontSize: 14,
            titleFontSize: 16,
            xPadding: 20,
            yPadding: 20,
            //Custom Tooltip Element
            custom: function(tooltip) {
                var tooltipEl = '';
                tooltipEl = document.getElementById('custom_tooltip');

                if (!tooltipEl) {
                    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                    tooltipEl.id = 'custom_tooltip';
                    tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
                    document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
                }

                // Hide if no tooltip
                if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
                    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                    return;
                }

                // Set caret Position
                tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
                if (tooltip.yAlign) {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltip.yAlign);
                } else {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
                }

                function getBody(bodyItem) {
                    return bodyItem.lines;
                }

                // Set Text
                if (tooltip.body) {
                    var titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
                    var bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(getBody);

                    var innerHtml = '<thead>';
                    var inHeadStyle = 'padding-bottom:10px;';
                    titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                        innerHtml += '<tr><th style="' + inHeadStyle + '">' + title + '</th></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                    bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {

                        var colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];
                        var colorType = "";

                        //If chart is Kagi plot, pick border color
                        if (pointStyle == 0) {
                            colorType = colors.borderColor;
                        } else { //if scatter plot pick background color
                            colorType = colors.backgroundColor;
                        }

                        var style = 'background:' + colorType;
                        style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                        style += '; border-width: 2px';

                        var inStyle = 'text-align:left;';

                        var span = '<span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="' + style + '"></span>';

                        var innerContent = '<td>' + span + body + '</td>';

                        // Every even/odd create a new tr
                        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                            innerHtml += '<tr style="' + inStyle + '"> ' + innerContent;
                        } else {
                            innerHtml += innerContent + '</tr>';
                        }
                    });

                    // If is a odd number of itens close the last open tr
                    if (bodyLines.count % 2 == 1) {
                        innerHtml += '</tr></tbody>';
                    } else {
                        innerHtml += '</tbody>';
                    }

                    var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
                }

                var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                // Display, position, and set styles for font               
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
                tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
                tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._bodyFontFamily;
                tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.bodyFontSize + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._bodyFontStyle;
                tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            },
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    var prefix = data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label;
                    return prefix + " : " + tooltipItems.yLabel;
                },
                title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    var value = tooltipItems[0].xLabel;
                    return xAxisLabel + " : " + value;
                }
            }
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: xAxisLabel
                },
                ticks: {
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 90,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMin: 0,
                    autoSkip: false
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: yAxisLabel
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMin: 0
                }
            }]
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        spanGaps: true,
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: position,
            labels: {
                fontSize: 13,
                padding: 10
            }
        },
        elements: {
            point: {
                pointStyle: pointStyle
            }
        }
    }

    return options;
}
```